# Play 2.6x Scala app does not log despite logback configuration

Tags: scala, playframework

I'm trying to enable logging in my Play 2.6 Scala app.

I've basically implemented this logging filter to log each request processed by the server: https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.6.x/ScalaHttpFilters.

I cannot for the life of me get the logs to show in either the console OR the specific `log/` directory. I've tried everything from playing around with my `logback.xml` file and my app config.

Does anyone have any ideas where I'm going wrong? The filter I wrote is being processed on request (I set a breakpoint to ensure).

**logback.xml:**

```
<!-- https://www.playframework.com/documentation/latest/SettingsLogger -->
<configuration>

    <conversionRule conversionWord="coloredLevel" converterClass="play.api.libs.logback.ColoredLevel" />

    <appender name="FILE" class="ch.qos.logback.core.FileAppender">
        <file>${application.home:-.}/logs/application.log</file>
        <encoder>
            <pattern>%date [%level] from %logger in %thread - %message%n%xException</pattern>
        </encoder>
    </appender>

    <appender name="STDOUT" class="ch.qos.logback.core.ConsoleAppender">
        <encoder>
            <pattern>%coloredLevel %logger{15} - %message%n%xException{10}</pattern>
        </encoder>
    </appender>

    <appender name="ASYNCFILE" class="ch.qos.logback.classic.AsyncAppender">
        <appender-ref ref="FILE" />
    </appender>

    <appender name="ASYNCSTDOUT" class="ch.qos.logback.classic.AsyncAppender">
        <appender-ref ref="STDOUT" />
    </appender>

    <logger name="play" level="INFO" />
    <logger name="application" level="DEBUG" />

    <!-- Off these ones as they are annoying, and anyway we manage configuration ourselves -->
    <logger name="com.avaje.ebean.config.PropertyMapLoader" level="OFF" />
    <logger name="com.avaje.ebeaninternal.server.core.XmlConfigLoader" level="OFF" />
    <logger name="com.avaje.ebeaninternal.server.lib.BackgroundThread" level="OFF" />
    <!--<logger name="org.jdbcdslog.StatementLogger"  level="DEBUG" /> &lt;!&ndash; Will log all statements &ndash;&gt;-->
    <!--<logger name="slick.jdbc.JdbcBackend.statement"  level="DEBUG" />-->

    <logger name="com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.javascript" level="OFF" />

    <root level="INFO">
        <appender-ref ref="ASYNCFILE" />
        <appender-ref ref="ASYNCSTDOUT" />
    </root>

</configuration>
```

**LoggingFilter.scala:**

```
package filters

import javax.inject.Inject
import akka.stream.Materializer
import play.api.Logger
import play.api.mvc._
import scala.concurrent.{ExecutionContext, Future}

class LoggingFilter @Inject() (implicit val mat: Materializer, ec: ExecutionContext) extends Filter {

  def apply(nextFilter: RequestHeader => Future[Result])
           (requestHeader: RequestHeader): Future[Result] = {

    Logger.debug("Hi!") // Why you no work!!

    val startTime = System.currentTimeMillis

    nextFilter(requestHeader).map { result =>

      val endTime = System.currentTimeMillis
      val requestTime = endTime - startTime

      Logger.info(s"${requestHeader.method} ${requestHeader.uri} took ${requestTime}ms and returned ${result.header.status}")

      result.withHeaders("Request-Time" -> requestTime.toString)
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Is there anything in the log file? if so can you add it to the question?

Comment: For what it's worth, I dumped your `logback.xml` and your `LoggingFilter.scala` into a Play application and it logged "Hi!" just fine, so I assume your problem must be exogenous to these two files (i.e. editing them won't help).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, after several hours of debugging, I finally found the cause (could be helpful for others so posting here).

**Cause:**

The root cause of the issue is a conflicting logging dependency bundled in `play-silhoutte`. My app was using `play-silhoutte` version `5.0.3` which apparently contains a bug causing the Play logger to be overwritten by a logging configuration in a sub-dependency of `play-silhoutte`(`com.typesafe.play:play-openid_2.12:2.6.9`).

**Diagnosis:**

Unfortunately this took a long time to debug - combination of reading Play source code + debugging the stack frames as the `Logger` gets initialized. I noticed that the Logger was being initialized **twice** - once for the actual Play logger (with correct configuration as specified in my `logback.xml` then again as a result of `play-silhoutte` (effectively overwriting the good logger).

Looking at the initialization params, it was reading its `logback.xml` from `/Users/.../.ivy2/cache/com.typesafe.play/play-openid_2.12/jars/play-openid_2.12-2.6.9.jar!logback.xml`. I expanded the jar and found the following logging config:

```
<!--
  ~ Copyright (C) 2009-2017 Lightbend Inc. <https://www.lightbend.com>
  -->
<configuration>
    <!-- Suppress logback complaining about multiple logback-test.xml files -->
    <statusListener class="ch.qos.logback.core.status.NopStatusListener" />

    <appender name="STDOUT" class="ch.qos.logback.core.ConsoleAppender">
        <encoder>
            <!-- We use short exception stack trace logging to limit output for travis. -->
            <!-- Change to full if you need to do further debugging, but never commit that. -->
            <pattern>%level %logger{15} - %message%n%ex{short}</pattern>
        </encoder>
    </appender>

    <root level="WARN">
        <appender-ref ref="STDOUT" />
    </root>

</configuration>
```

At this point I knew it was a conflicting depedency issue.

**Solution:**

After doing some digging, I actually found a [bug open on Github](https://github.com/mohiva/play-silhouette/issues/538) describing my issue. I was running `play-silhoutte` version `5.0.3` so bumping it to `5.0.4` fixed the issue.